# Bootstrap: Own classes necessary?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Im wondering how to use the bootstrap framework in a proper way.

I have a `row` with just one `col-lg-12`. I just want to hold a list with divs so I thought it would be best to include one row for each "row" with alway just one colum. However: Within that col's Im positioning the content with my own classes via absolute positioning.

My problem now: When resizing the window its ends up in a mess because its not responisble. Sure I could override my own absolute-classes with media-queries for each display-case but is this a good approach? Is there a way to only use bootstrap within the div?

The Image shows the div with the absolute content. The whole div (with the glowing border) is the colum (`col-lg-12`).
[image: inner content]

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using bootstrap classes for your div but only so they get the correct width for responsiveness. If the top div is set to `position:relative` the child divs will react correctly when resizing

Or you could rethink your approach, according to this image, you don't really need to use absolute positioning to achieve this layout.

Something like this could work

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="col-xs-9"> <!-- Left col -->
        <div class="top"></div>
        <div class="bottom"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3"> <!-- right col -->
        <div class="fullHeight"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: nice approach! But the problem is, that fullHeight has to be positioned "absolut" as well to get the full height-effect. Also the bottom-div has to be positioned by "absolute positioning" at the bottom. Or how would you do it?